# Getting part of URL after redirect

Tags: python

OK, here's basically what I am trying to do:

The URL [http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=animelist&adb.search="Cowboy Bebop"&do.search=search](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=animelist&adb.search=%22Cowboy%20Bebop%22&do.search=search) redirects to http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=23

Let's say I want to write down the ID (23, in that example) in a XML file.

Comment: More information -- do you really want a python solution? Why are your scripts in perl? Where does the python come into play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of `urlopen` has method `geturl` which provides the redirect information. Then you can parse it using regular expression.

```
import urllib2
import re

url = 'http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=animelist&adb.search=%22Cowboy%20Bebop%22&do.search=search'
headers = {"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
request = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
r =  re.search("aid=(\d+)", result.geturl())
print r.group(1)
```

Comment: Should probably use a library like `urlparse` instead of `regex`

Comment: Probably should. I have never used it. Feel free to improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var uri = window.location.href
var params = uri.split("?")[1].split("&");

args = {};
for(var i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
    p = params[i].split("=");
    args[p[0]] = p[1];
}
alert(args['aid']);
```

[EDIT: Saw python tag]

So, in python, if you have a URL, you could split it very similarly:

```
uri = "http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=23"
params = uri.split('?')[1].split('&')

args={}
for kv in params:
     p = kv.split('=')
     args[p[0]] = p[1]
```

But again, I have no idea where python comes into play in your question, as it seems the scripts getting hit are perl.

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be `python`?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I believe the downvote was because this is Javascript for a question tagged Python. OP is probably looking for server-side solution.

Comment: my bad ... so where does the URL come into play with python? I only see perl scripts

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to the actual coding question. But you might want to use the [AniDB search data](http://wiki.anidb.net/w/HTTP_API_Definition#Search) instead of querying their website.